# Send XMLHttpRequest behind proxy

Tags: javascript, proxy, xmlhttprequest

I want to execute a POST via the XMLHttpRequest Object below in TypeScript. Sadly I keep getting the following error:

```
407: Proxy Authentication Failed. Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request.
```

My Code:

```
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.withCredentials = true;
        oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        oReq.open("POST", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", true, clientID, secret);
        oReq.onload = function() {
            console.log(oReq.responseText);
        };
        oReq.send();
```

I went through several Posts on how to configure a proxy for these requests but nothing really worked. Since our Proxy only supports ntlm I tried installing cntlm and setting the proxy to     `http://credentials@localhost:Port` which worked for installing stuff via npm but sadly not for this issue. The only thing I did not try is configuring the proxy within the code. I did not find a way to configure it with my credentials which I need to pass.

Comment: XmlHttpRequests are authenticated transparently by the browser's proxy settings. This should not occur at all unless something is fishy in the browser configuration.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it :) Since I am using it via the Emulator it is going to use the npm proxy, isn't it?

Comment: Some thoughts: 1) So many websites today use XHRs as an integral part of their functioning, you would have noticed it if they were blocked by your proxy in principle. 2) When the website is HTTPS then the proxy usually cannot even see what you are doing. Loading images, loading regular HTML, issuing an Ajax requests, it's all equally encrypted and indistinguishable. 3) Make sure that your code runs in the right security context. Automated scripts for example might use a different account with different proxy configurations or rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use the XHR in my context via emulator, since I was using Xcode 7. Xcode does not support the usage of a proxy that requires authentication since Xcode 6.

Reference:

> iOS Simulator does not support the use of network proxy servers that
>   require authentication. (14889876)

from the [Xcode 6 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html).